# WebCenter Sites stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-adf, webcenter

How do I change the stylesheet in WebCenter Sites? I've read through Oracle's documentation and I'm still not sure where it would be located (the original developer left).

I have also begun working on converting other sites in our corporate portfolio and I'm not sure where to drop the CSS or JS files.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the folder including css files, js files and img inside cs folder.
And in your template, to reference your static files, you should start with the name of the folder including the statics.

For example :
[image: folder structure]

Based on folder structure in the image, we will reference our css file using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/statics/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your configuration. For example, you can have an apache server and get css in apache directory. You have just to configure you're virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /cs>
        SetHandler weblogic-handler
        WebLogicHost 192.168.3.1
        WebLogicPort 7003
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /css/$1 [L,PT]
    RewriteRule ^/cs/(.*)$ /cs/$1 [L,PT]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /cs/{sitecode}/$1 [L,PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create in WCS console administration:

1. Document Attribute
2. Document Definition with the Document Attribute.

Then you can create a new document where to upload your `css` file. Just import that document in your `html`.